# Mongoose how to update entire object back to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

From a Products collection (Mongoose Schema) I get all products belonging to a specific dealer into a javascript array of objects.

Later, after remove, update and add some items, I need to take back this object into the collection with all changes.

There is some all-in-one way quick and elegant to performance this action in Mongoose or MongoDB?

Comment: Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772656/mongoose-how-to-update-entire-object-back-to-database/39774086#39774086) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need any improvements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of Mongose documents, for example in an array called `documents` then you can change any one of them - for example the first one with:

```
documents[0].field = 'new value';
```

and save it with:

```
documents[0].save(function (err, updated) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle success
  }
});
```

See the Mongoose documentation for more info:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html